# how to send click on a element using selenium in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to send click on a element in python but it returns the element in not clickable
actually it is clickable
what i am doing wrong?
my link is ('https://www.instagram.com/p/BhZM1kADqm7/?taken-by=bbcpersian')
and the element is:

```
post = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_ebcx9')
comment_list = post.find_element_by_tag_name('ul')
comments = comment_list.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
```

and the element I'm trying to sen click is `comments[1]`

Comment: Are you trying to click this element? <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _95hvo" title="bbcpersian" href="/bbcpersian/">bbcpersian</a>

Comment: On which element you are trying to click ?

Comment: im using chrome and the element is <a class="_m3m1c _1s3cd" href="#" role="button">Load more comments</a>